# How to make FFMPEG accessible in CMD

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg

I need to make FFMPEG accessible from the CMD prompt in Windows 7. I think it has something to do with setting an Environmental Variable, but I can't remember how.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the ffmpeg bin location i.e. C:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin or where ever you installed it, to your systems PATH environmental variable.  See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for info on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple but just couldn't find it.